# (drupal)a difficulty code to understand,get the same article's title under the same term

Tags: module, drupal, drupal-taxonomy

```
if ($node->taxonomy) {
 $query = 'SELECT DISTINCT(t.nid), n.nid, n.title FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {term_node}    t ON n.nid = t.nid WHERE n.nid != %d AND (';


 $args = array($node->nid);
   $tids = array();

  foreach ($node->taxonomy as $term) {
  $tids[] = 't.tid = %d';
  $args[] = $term->tid;
}

  $query .= implode(' OR ', $tids) .  ')';

 $result = db_query_range($query, $args, 0, 10);
while ($o = db_fetch_object($result)) {
echo l($o->title, 'node/' . $o->nid);
}
```

}

the code is from a drupal guru. . used to get the article's title under the same term in node.tpl.php, i have researched it two days, although know some part of it. the principle of the code i still don't know. expect someone can explain more details about it for me .many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short version:**

It **gets the array of tags** of the node, **retrieves the first 10 nodes** that use at least one of these tags and **outputs a link for each** of these 10 results.

---

**Detailed version:**

First of all, the variable "`$node`" is an object that contains the data about a specific node (e.g. a Page or Story node).
For example, "`$node->title`" would be the title of that node.

---

"`$node->taxonomy`" tests is that node is tagged (because if it has no tags, it cannot retrieve the other nodes using the same tag(s).
When there is one or several tags associated with that node/page/story, `$node->taxonomy` is an `array` .

---

Now about the SQL query:
 "`node`" is the database table that stores the base fields (non-CCK) of every node.
 "`term_node`" is the database table that contains the combination of tag (which is called a "`taxonomy term`") and node.

---

In both tables, "`nid`" is the "`unique Node ID`" (which is an internal autoincremented number). Because this column is in both tables, this is how the tables are joined together.

In "`term_node`", "`tid`" is the "`unique Term ID`" (which is also an internal autoincremented number).

---

The "`node`" table is aliased "`n`", therefore "`n.nid`" means "`the Node ID stored in table node`".
The "`term_node`" table is aliased "`t`", therefore "`t.tid`" means "`the Term ID stored in table term_node`".

---

The "`foreach`" loop goes thru the array of tags to extract the *TermID* of each tag used by the node in order to add it in the SQL query, and implode converts to a string.

The loop stores a piece of SQL query for each tag in variable `$tids` and stores the actual value in variable `$args` because Drupal database calls are safer when the arguments are passed separately from the SQL query: "`%d`" means "`integer number`".

---

"`db_query_range`" is a function that selects multiple rows in the database: here, "`0 10`" means "`retrieve the first 10 results`".

---

"`db_fetch_object`" in the "`while`" loop retrieves each result and stores it in the variable "`$o`", which is an object.

Therefore "`$o->title`" contains the value of the column "`title`" retrieved by the SQL query.

---

The function "`l`" is the drupal functin that creates the code for an HTML link: the first argument is the name of the link, the second argument is the drupal path: in Drupal, any node can be accessed by default using  "`www.yoursite.com/node/NodeID`",
which is why it gives the path "`node/123`" (where `123` is the "`Node ID`").

This function is useful because it transparently handles custom paths, so if your node has a custom path to access it using "`www.yoursite.com/my-great-page`" instead, it will create a link to that page instead of "`www.yoursite.com/node/123`" automatically.

Comment: you're my hero. many many thanks. but there'are some parts i can't follow well. "n "term_node", "tid" is the "unique Term ID" (which is also an internal autoincremented number)." 
i took a look at the table"term_node", there're same rows with the same tid.

Comment: why i shoud do these two lines"$args = array($node->nid); 
   $tids = array();"

Comment: in foreach loop,where is the  $term from, how i know it's an object.

Comment: $term comes from the "foreach" loop: is it the value of a single tag from the $node->taxonomy array.

Comment: "$args = array($node->nid); $tids = array()" is the initialisation of the two variables used to build the part of the SQL query depending on the list of "Term ID". The only thing to note is that $args contain already one value because at line 2 in the SQL statement, there is "WHERE n.nid != %d" (which excludes the current node from the query), which is why it needs the value of the "Node ID" for Drupal to place it in the SQL instead of "%d".

Comment: (ah I wish stackoverflow would allow better formatting of comments: it's harder to post code in comments than in the answer itself)

Comment: "$node->taxonomy" is an array of objects because the Taxonomy module implements "hook_load" to preprocess nodes to add this property, that is how you know that it's an object.

Comment: The TermID is unique, but it comes from a third table "term_data" that isn't used in the SQL, so I didn't mention it. In "term_node", "tid" references that unique id, however in "term_node", there is one row per association "tag<->node", so there are multiple rows with the same "tid" if a tag is used by several nodes; the same way, there are multiple rows with the same "nid" if a node has several tags.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't exactly call the guy who wrote this a guru, you could do this a lot prettier. Anyways what he does it create a query that looks like this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(t.nid), n.nid, n.title FROM {node} n
 INNER JOIN {term_node} t ON n.nid = t.nid
 WHERE n.nid != %d
 AND (t.tid = %d OR t.tid = %d OR ... t.tid = %d);
```

The end result is that he selects all the node ids and titles (only once) that share at least one term with the selected node, but isn't the node itself.

Comment: thank you, you're also a guru. but your answer is too abstract. i can't follow it well.i don't know how this line "(t.tid = %d OR t.tid = %d OR ... t.tid = %d);" from.